# How to get weekly dates in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query which outputs weekly dates from a given date to the end of the current year.
I am stuck here:

```
Select DATE_ADD(input_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
as alarm_date from userInput;
```

How do I get all the dates?

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina it is  v8.0.26

Comment: Post a data sample from your userInput table plus desired output (both as text).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, input_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY alarm_date FROM userInput
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id, alarm_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY FROM cte WHERE YEAR(alarm_date) = YEAR(NOW()) )
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

Comment: The table name is userInput, also, I need the input_date in the output as well.

Comment: @SinghKushal Updated. I add `id` to the output list for to identify what source row the alarm dates are generated for.